# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, 525-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted on sending email on Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail

When I use mailer to send myself an email whenever a lead is generated, I get the `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.` error.

My myrealdomain.com email is set up with Gmail. I still get the error after I allowed less secure apps on Google.

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "myrealdomain.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "email@myrealdomain.com",
    password: "correctPassword!"
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
```

Is there anything else I can try to overcome this issue? Before I allowed access to less secure apps, I got a critical warning email from Google that someone is trying to get an access to my email account, so I know that the email is working.

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication enable on your GMail account ?

Comment: just checked it and the 2-step verification was OFF.

Answer (score 0):

It solved it when I

1. Turned on the access to less secure apps on the admin panel on Gmail setting.
2. Disabled CAPTCHA on Gmail setting.
3. Turned off 2-step authentication on Gmail setting.
4. Changed domain to `domain: 'smtp.gmail.com'` on `development.rb`

Now, it works when I hard code the user_name and the password on `config>environments>development.rb`.

**PROBLEM**

But when I put the user_name and the password into environment variables, It gives me `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required.`

Comment: This should work. Even with env variables.
What did you use to set the ENV variables? How and where did you use them?